# Direction Of Light From LightSource RayTracing

Tags: c#, graphics, geometry, raytracing

Okay so I have this class

```
public sealed class LightSource
{
    public readonly Point3D Source;
    public readonly Point3D Direction;

    public readonly float ConeAngle;

    public List<Ray> Lights { get; private set; }

    public const double MaxRadian = 2.0 * Math.PI;

    public LightSource(Point3D source, Point3D direction, float coneAngle)
    {
        this.Source = source;
        this.Direction = direction;

        if (coneAngle <= 0 || coneAngle > LightSource.MaxRadian)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("coneAngle <= 0 || coneAngle > LightSource.MaxRadian");
        }

        this.ConeAngle = coneAngle;
        this.Lights = LightSource.GenerateLights(this.Source, this.Direction, this.ConeAngle);
    }

    public static List<Ray> GenerateLights(Point3D source, Point3D direction, float coneAngle)
    {
        //How would i do this?
    }
}
```

How would I realize the method GenerateLights to give me a list of rays that are inside my cone angle.
Lets say the amount of rays will be some constant.
Thank You.

Comment: Stackoverflow has a pretty high standard for questions, they generally expect that you have tried to solve it yourself first and can point to the exact part where what you tried didn't work. You may want to try solving this yourself before asking others to do it for you.

Comment: I tried solving this... and I just couldn't. I didn't want to show my ugly code. I'm also pretty naïve to this field and I'm 15. Sorry if seems like I'm being lazy.

Comment: One thing you may do to help is to tell us whether your difficulty is figuring out *what* to do (the math part), or *how* to code it into C#. If it's the former, then you should be able to describe what you've done without showing any code. If it's the latter, then tell us the answer to the first part so we only need to work on the part you haven't yet figured out.

Comment: I'm okay with the actual coding part. I need the math part.

Comment: In that case, perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com/ may be more helpful? I'm no expert but stackoverflow is generally about programming, not so much geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert, but just to give you a starting point: perhaps you could put a grid perpendicular to the direction you're aiming, and only keep the rays whose angle from the direction is within coneAngle?

ASCII art:

```
                                      +--+--+
                                      |  |  |
                                      +--+--+
                     direction        |  |  |    
staring point ----------------------> +--+--+
                                      |  |  |
                                      +--+--+
                                      |  |  |  
                                      +--+--+
```

imagine the grid is perpendicular to the "direction" vector.